# Prove that $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} 1/(k+1) {2k\choose k} {n\choose 2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction, contest-math, recurrence-relations

> Consider the sequence defined by $a_0 = a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+2 } = a_{n+1} + \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$ for $n\ge 0$. Prove that $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} 1/(k+1) {2k\choose k} {n\choose 2k}$.

The $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$ term in the recurrence relation for $a_{n+2}$ reminds me of the Catalan numbers, as does the ${2k\choose k}/(k+1)$ term in the proposed formula for $a_n$. So I think it might be useful to use properties of Catalan numbers to solve this problem (e.g. the generating function for the Catalan numbers $f(x)$ satisfies $xf(x)^2 - f(x)+1=0$). It might be useful to find an explicit formula for the generating function $f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n$, and this may be related to that of the Catalan numbers in some way. But the given recurrence seems very hard to work with, as well as the stated formula. Is there some way to simplify the formula? To simplify the recurrence, one trick that's used is to substitute $n+1$ for n in the recurrence relation for a given sequence and then subtract common terms. But there don't appear to be a lot of common terms in $a_{n+1} + \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$ and $a_{n+2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_k a_{n+1-k}$. I'm not sure if induction is useful.

Comment: These are called the Motzkin numbers - searching for that may help you find some more information! Probably the nicest way to prove this is by interpreting both quantities combinatorially (knowing about Catalan numbers) as the number of Motzkin paths of length $n$ - ie, if you're walking around $\Bbb N$, and each step you take is forward, backwards, or doesn't move you, how many sequences of steps of length $n$-ish take you from $0$ back to $0$?

Comment: Since you brought up generating functions, can you find a similar expression for $M(x)$? Hint: Look at $x^2M(x)^2$ as a convolution. This gives you a quadratic, which you can solve. (However, It's less clear to me how that leads to the closed form)

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the recurrence we have for the generating function $M(z)$
that

$$[z^{n+2}] M(z) = [z^{n+1}] M(z) + [z^n] M(z)^2.$$

Multiply by $w^n$ and sum to infinity to get

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} w^n [z^{n+2}] M(z) = 
\sum_{n\ge 0} w^n [z^{n+1}] M(z) + M(w)^2$$

or

$$w^{-2} \sum_{n\ge 0} w^{n+2} [z^{n+2}] M(z) = 
w^{-1} \sum_{n\ge 0} w^{n+1} [z^{n+1}] M(z) + M(w)^2$$

which is

$$w^{-2} (M(w) - w - 1) = w^{-1} (M(w)-1) + M(w)^2.$$

Solve this to obtain

$$M(w) = \frac{1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w^2}$$

which is indeed [OEIS A001006](https://oeis.org/A001006), Motzkin
numbers. Note that we get

$$\frac{1}{M(w)} = \frac{2w^2}{1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}
\\ = 2w^2 \frac{1-w+\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{(1-w)^2-(1-2w-3w^2)}
= - w^2 \frac{-1+w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w^2}
\\ = - w^2 \left(M(w) - \frac{1}{w^2} + \frac{1}{w}\right)
= 1-w-w^2 M(w).$$

On the other hand we have working with

$$\overset{\sim}{M}(w) =
\sum_{n\ge 0} w^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
\frac{1}{k+1} {2k\choose k} {n\choose 2k}$$

that

$${n\choose 2k} {2k\choose k} =
\frac{n!}{(n-2k)! \times k! \times k!}
= {n\choose k} {n-k\choose n-2k}$$

and obtain

$$\overset{\sim}{M}(w) =
\sum_{n\ge 0} w^n 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
\frac{1}{k+1} {n\choose k} {n-k\choose n-2k}
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n [z^n] (1+z)^n
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{k+1} {n\choose k} (1+z)^{-k} z^{2k}.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor in
$z$. Continuing,

$$\overset{\sim}{M}(w) =
\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^n}{n+1} [z^n] (1+z)^n
\sum_{k\ge 0} {n+1\choose k+1} (1+z)^{-k} z^{2k}
\\ =
\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^n}{n+1} [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} z^{-2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {n+1\choose k+1} (1+z)^{-k-1} z^{2(k+1)}
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^n}{n+1} [z^{n+2}] (1+z)^{n+1}
\left(-1 + \left[ 1 + \frac{z^2}{1+z} \right]^{n+1}\right).$$

The contribution from the minus one term is zero and we find
for the inner term

$$[z^{n+2}] (1+z)^{n+1}
\left[ 1 + \frac{z^2}{1+z} \right]^{n+1}
= [z^{n+2}] [1+z+z^2]^{n+1}.$$

The contribution from $z$ is

$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} [1+z+z^2]^{n+1}.$$

Now put $z= v M(v)$ so that $z/(1+z+z^2) = v$ and $dz = ( M(v) +  
v M'(v)) \; dv$ to get

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^2 M(v)^2} \frac{1}{v^{n+1}} (M(v)+vM'(v))
= - \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}} \left(\frac{1}{v M(v)}\right)'.$$

We thus have

$$\overset{\sim}{M}(w) =
- \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^n}{n+1}
\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}} \left(\frac{1}{v M(v)}\right)'$$

so that

$$w \overset{\sim}{M}(w) =
- \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^{n+1}}{n+1}
[v^n] \left(\frac{1}{v M(v)}\right)'
\\ = - \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^{n+1}}{n+1}
[v^n] \left(\frac{1}{v}-1-vM(v)\right)' = w M(w)$$

and we finally have

$$\overset{\sim}{M}(w) = M(w)$$

as desired.

Comment: Great answer. (+1)